# python raw socket listner not running through cron

Tags: python, sockets, cron

I have a raw socket python program. It runs manually, but when i schedule it to run on reboot through cron, it doesnt start.
Here is the code:

```
import socket
BUF_SIZE = 65535
ETH_P_ALL = 3
Interface = "eth0"
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
sock.bind((Interface, ETH_P_ALL))
sock.setblocking(0)
while True:
   try:
      packet = sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
   except socket.error:
      pass
   else:
      file = open("/home/user/Log.txt","a")
      file.write(packet)
```

Iam sending data but it doesn't write it to the file. I have to run it manually every time after boot to catch the packets. Unable to run it on boot through cron.

here is the crontab content:

```
@reboot python /home/user/receiver.py
```

Comment: Is it running before the inet (or whatever is being used) service is started?

Comment: No its not running the script at all. Even before the socket creation

Comment: Have you added a new line at the end of the crontab entry?